# Access child window method from parent in fancybox

Tags: asp.net, fancybox, fancybox-2

A.aspx opens a fancybox modal window of b.aspx means here a.aspx is parent and b.aspx is child.

Requirement is on clicking the close button, it will trigger a method of child window(b.aspx) and that method will close the window on if...else condition.

The problem I am facing is I am not able to call the child window method on fancybox window close.

I have tried with 'beforeClose' event to call the child method, but it is throwing error with 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

The fancybox is an object of the parent so something like the following will need to be done from the child:
parent.fancybox.close();